# How can I use filter in Pandas when I want to filter only partial values in column using python pandas?

Tags: python, pandas

I want to filter on Timeline column only "**Jan**".

```
Timeline    Goods   Price
Jan-2018    Sugar   100
Jan-2017    Wheat   150
Feb- 2018   Sugar   120
Feb-2017    Sugar   125
```

Output:

```
Timeline    Goods   Price
Jan-2018    Sugar   100
Jan-2017    Wheat   150
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [`str.startswith`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.str.startswith.html) with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[df['Timeline'].str.startswith('Jan')]
print (df)
   Timeline  Goods  Price
0  Jan-2018  Sugar    100
1  Jan-2017  Wheat    150
```

If working with `datetime`s compare by [`dt.month`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.dt.month.html):

```
df['Timeline'] = pd.to_datetime(df['Timeline'])

df = df[df['Timeline'].dt.month==1]
print (df)
    Timeline  Goods  Price
0 2018-01-01  Sugar    100
1 2017-01-01  Wheat    150
```